# Cisco DS-C9148S-k9 9.2(1a) unable to launch device manager

Tags: java, switch-statement, cisco

I recently installed firmware version 9.2 (1a) on the Cisco DS-C9148S-k9 switch and I can't start the device manager, does anyone know what the problem would be?

I tried many different versions of Java and the latest.

Error is :
Unable to launch application / JNLP Jar download failure.

Details:

Launch File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://*sw IP*">
<information>
<title>Cisco Device Manager</title>
<vendor>Cisco Systems, Inc.</vendor>
<description>Device Manager</description>
<description kind="short">Cisco Device Manager</description>
<icon href="andiamo32.gif"/>
<offline-allowed/>
</information>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.7+" java-vm-args="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"/>
<jar href="boot.jar"/>
<jar href="installer.jar"/>
<jar href="log4j.jar"/>
</resources>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<application-desc main-class="com.cisco.dcbu.install.Boot">
<argument>-main=com.cisco.dcbu.dm.DM</argument>
<argument>-home=*sw IP*</argument>
<argument>-version=9.2(1a)</argument>
<argument>-https=true</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: JNLP Jar download failure.
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.validateResults(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadEagerorAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried many different versions of Java and the latest.
Tried to run element-manager.jnlp file from CMD as administrator.
I put switch IP into java security exceptions.

Comment: in case someone roam into this, might be useful: install JRE 8 u321 (later and previous vesrions wont work), clear jJava cache, uninstall all other version of Java. Tested on Win10, Win 11, Win 2019.